# How to create android Login activity with email id and password using parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parser

How to create android Login activity with email id and password using parse ?

Comment: Parse is shutting down, why are you using it?

Comment: @Keshav Parse never "shut down". It is now open-source and has a thriving community. See here: https://parseplatform.org/

Answer (score -1):

Check out this one..Simple tutorial for login and sign up with parse.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/